# An exception of type 'The skip navigation is not a collection' is thrown for a property implementing ICollection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using Ef Core 5.0.1, I have a many-to-many relationship:

```
public class User : Entity<User>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role : Entity<Role>
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

The many-to-many relationnship is configured as followed:

```
builder.HasMany(u => u.Roles)
   .WithMany(r => r.Users)
   .UsingEntity<UserRole>(
       c => c.HasOne(c => c.Role).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.RoleId),
       c => c.HasOne(c => c.User).WithMany().HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId))
   .HasKey(c => new { c.UserId, c.RoleId });
```

This configuration works. However, `Entity<T>` implements `IList<T>`. It does that by inhereting from this class:

```
public abstract class ModelBase<T> : IList<T> where T : ModelBase<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _items;

    public bool IsReadOnly => false;
    public int Count => this._items.Count;
    public T this[int index] { get => this._items[index]; set => this._items[index] = value; }

    protected ModelBase()
    {
        this._items = new List<T>();
    }

    protected ModelBase(T item) : this()
    {
        this.Add(item);
    }

    protected ModelBase(IEnumerable<T> items) : this()
    {
        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public void Populate()
    {
        if (this.Count == 0)
        {
            this.Add((T)this);
        }
    }

    public void Populate(int count)
    {
        this.AddRange(new List<T>(count));
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        this._items.Add(item);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        this._items.AddRange(items);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        this._items.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return this._items.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        this._items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return this._items.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        this._items.Insert(index, item);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return this._items.Remove(item);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        this._items.RemoveAt(index);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._items.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

If I remove the explicit implementation of ICollection on both skip navigation properties:

```
public class User : Entity<User>
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Role Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role : Entity<Role>
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public User Users { get; set; }
}
```

The solution builds with the same many-to-many configuration, but when I try to access the database, I get a runtime exception: `System.InvalidOperationException : The skip navigation 'User.Roles' is not a collection. Only collection skip navigation properties are currently supported.` Is there a workaround to make this work?

Comment: Why exactly do you not want to use `ICollection<>` or `IList<>` for the `Roles` and `Users` navigation properties?

Comment: @Progman I'm using a model where entities are collections of themselves. User being Entity<User> is already implementing ILitst<User>. So User is a collection of User. if in Role I put ICollection<User> I'll be having a collection of collections of User. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Is `Entity` your own class? If so please [edit] your question to include the source code of that class? Also, what do you mean by "User is a collection of User"? Include the database table structure to your question as well.

Comment: An entity never *is* a collection of itself. That design will bring you nowhere.

Comment: `entities are collections of themselves` - who gave you that idea?!! That's not the concept of `Entity` in Entity Framework. An `Entity` in EF is a plain object, not a collection of objects.

Comment: I updated the question with the implementation asked. The utility of this model is to have the ability of treating a model either as a single element or as a collection. For the entity case, my repo contains a single persistence method Save(T entity) (where T : Entity<T>) that is used for single and bulk operations. I can pass it a single user, User user = new User(), or or after adding other multiple users by doing something like user.Add(new User()). Nothing but OOP, evey object is a collection of itself.

Comment: @Mouad Why is it an issue when you define the collection navigation properties as `ICollection<>`? That is the correct way of saying "the user X has these following roles". If you have only a property like `Role Roles {get; set}` you will not be able to say that the user X has these (multiple) roles, you can select only one.

Comment: This has nothing to with OOP where one of the driving forces is separation of concerns. Your entity is heavily overloaded. Also, what about Liskov? I'm sure that your repository has to ask each object what it is, a single entity or a list. And what about application code? How do you ensure that you assign the right type of object to a navigation property?

Comment: @Progman Role Roles {get; set;} can say that the user has multiple roles as i can iterate over Role (it implements IEnumerable<Role>). builder.HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithMany(r => r.Users) wasn't botherd by the fact that both navigation properties are objects as both are enumerable. It compiles but fails only at runtime.

Comment: @GertArnold I disagree. Entity has the behaviour of a collection that is encapsulated in a base type. Liskov is safe, in my repo all I do is iterate over  my object (as it is enumerable) and persist every element. The application code is type safe. For instance, user.Roles = new User() wont work as User : Entity<User>, wherheas Role : Entity<Role>. By the way, the code work when the navigation property is "Entity<Role> Roles" instead of "Role Roles".

Comment: So if you save one entity it has to be a list of itself? Incredible. OK, one last try to get you off this dead end. Try to make a reference navigation property instead of a collection navigation property. Good luck.

Comment: @GertArnold Thank's for your comments. I understand that the concept is counter-intuitive, but it violates nothing in OOP or SOLID. Entity is just an object that implements IList and thus can behave like a collection. If you instanciate a user, User user = new User(), it's an object that behaves like an empty collection. if you do this: user.Add(new User()), it's an object that behaves like a collection of 1 element, and so on. Deciding if the relation is 1-to-many or many-to-many can be done by fluent configuration in EF, and by domain validation rules at the domain layer. Greetings!